# Decommissioning DataStax cassandra node

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise

Trying to decommission 10 nodes from a 20 node cluster(each node has approx 50GB of data). How many nodes at a time can I decommission and what is the maximum number of nodes that can be decommissioned at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

Well, it depends. There isn't a right answer really (I guess I am setting myself up for being edited).

You want to make sure that you don't cross ranges as you decommission. C* will prevent you from doing that, but it's still good to ensure that yourself for a smooth transition. So this will defined how many you can decommission at once. If you do the decommissioning in chunks make sure you give gossip 2 minutes between operations to settle down.

Another factor is stress on the ring from streaming, so you may want to reduce the number of nodes, as to not affect regular operations on the ring. But that depends on your load as well as how close you are maxing out your setups limitations (network, disk i/O, etc.)

Do look at http://aryanet.com/blog/shrinking-the-cassandra-cluster-to-fewer-nodes for a different approach (if you are already in the cloud).